# Connecting to multiple db in scala

Tags: scala, slick, liquibase

I'm working on a project were I'm using Hikari, Liquibase, Slick for db related purposes.

Now I would like to separate the tables into multiple dbs. How exactly do I do that, such as if I want to query something, to know exactly which db should I query and of course to be able to connect to those dbs

Comment: Perhaps, this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364023/liquibase-on-multiple-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple if you use play-slick ... in the examples it explains how to: https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/basic

First you must declare the multiple configurations:
https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/conf/application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=sa
slick.dbs.default.db.password=""

slick.dbs.mydb.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.mydb.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.mydb.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
slick.dbs.mydb.db.user=sa
slick.dbs.mydb.db.password=""
```

Then use it when you inject it into your DAO (s):

**default** -> https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/app/dao/CatDAO.scala

```
class CatDAO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import profile.api._

  //...
}
```

**mydb** -> https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/app/dao/DogDAO.scala

```
class DogDAO @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("mydb") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
              import profile.api._

              //...
 }
```

If you do not use play-slick, you can look in the official documentation ... here is an example of how to declare it in the **MYSCHEMA** table:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.1/schemas.html

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, Some("MYSCHEMA"), "COFFEES") {
  //...
}
```

In our case we do not have an example that we connect to multiple databases with the same model ...
for that we inject it in the initialize at the beginning and inject it on demand by the selected APIKEY

Something else that could help you:

[Assign dynamically injected database name in Play Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493031/assign-dynamically-injected-database-name-in-play-slick)

http://gbmetzner.github.io/Multiple-DB/

Comment: I'm not using Play framework. Just Akka Http. But you have my upvote for effort :)